# Below is my Java program for finding duplicate. Here the output is repeated I want only duplicate character as output

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = sc.nextLine();
    int count = 0;

    // breaking in to characters
    char[] str1 = s1.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Duplicate are :");

    //creating outer loop for string length
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {

        //creating inner loop for comparison
        for (int j = i + 1; j < s1.length(); j++) {

            //comparing value of i and j
            if (str1[i] == str1[j]) {

                System.out.println(str1[j]);
                System.out.println(count);

                //increment after comparison
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
        aassdesdd
        Duplicate are :
        a
        s
        s
        d
        d
```

Comment: Remove all your comments and put one single code block pls.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print only consecutive duplicates? In your example you have 3 's's and 3 'd's, and you print 2 of each, so you only print the duplicates (but even if they are not consecutive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to print consecutive duplicates (i.e. for the input "aassdesdd", output asd and not assdd), you can combine the inner loop with the equality check:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < s1.length() && str1[i] == str1[j]; j++) {
        System.out.println(str1[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much the output is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to print consecutive distinct character, then you have only one loop, and each iteration, you can just check current and next character. If they are same, then print. To avoid same character printed again, we can have flag. This can be achieved using single loop

```
    char[] str1 = "aasssdesdd".toCharArray();
    boolean flag=true;
    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length-1; i++) {
        if (flag && str1[i]==str1[i+1])
        {
            System.out.println(str1[i]);
            // we found duplicate, mark the flag as false
            flag=false;
            continue;
        }
        flag = true;
   }
```

**Output :**

```
a
s
d
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/OOqVrM)**